# FreeRADIUS Perl Module "Unknown or invalid value "perl" for attribute Auth-Type"

Tags: perl, centos, freeradius

I am attempting to setup a FreeRadius Server with an OTP (LinOTP) backend in Centos 7. My issue is loading a perl module needed to link FreeRADIUS to LinOTP. No matter what I try I just keep getting the error below when I try starting radiusd (with "/usr/sbin/radiusd -C -lstdout -xx"):

```
/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[46]: Parse error (check) for entry DEFAULT: Unknown or invalid value "perl" for attribute Auth-Type
Failed reading /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

per documentation I have completed the following:

-added "DEFAULT Auth-type := perl" as the first and only uncommented line in /etc/raddb/users

-added the module location to /etc/raddb/mods-available/perl

-added the Auth-Type declarations in the site file (/etc/raddb/sites-available/linotp) see below.

-I have also tried copying the changes over to the default site but I get the same issue.

Here are the contents of the relevant files with comments removed (these things are 99% comments)
/etc/raddb/users

```
DEFAULT         Auth-type := perl
```

/etc/raddb/mods-available/perl

```
perl {
        filename = /etc/raddb/mods-config/perl/radius_linotp.pm
}
```

/etc/raddb/sites-available/linotp

```
authorize {
        files
        perl
        if (ok || updated) {
                update control {
                        Auth-Type := Perl
                }
        }
        preprocess
        chap
        mschap
        suffix
        unix
        expiration
        logintime
        pap
}
authenticate {
perl
        Auth-Type Perl {
                perl
         }
}
preacct {
        preprocess
        acct_unique
        suffix
        files
}
accounting {
        perl
        detail
        unix
        radutmp
        attr_filter.accounting_response
}
session {
        radutmp
}
post-auth {
        exec
        Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
                attr_filter.access_reject
        }
}
pre-proxy {
}
post-proxy {
}
```

/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize

```
DEFAULT         Auth-type := perl
```

and finally the verbose startup log from running /usr/sbin/radiusd -C -lstdout -x

```
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.13
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.dhcp
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.vqp
including dictionary file /etc/raddb/dictionary
including configuration file /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
including configuration file /etc/raddb/proxy.conf
including configuration file /etc/raddb/clients.conf
including files in directory /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cache_eap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/chap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/date
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dhcp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/digest
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dynamic_clients
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/echo
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/exec
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expiration
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expr
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/logintime
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/mschap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/passwd
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/preprocess
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/radutmp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/replicate
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/soh
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sradutmp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unix
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unpack
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/utf8
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/perl
including files in directory /etc/raddb/policy.d/
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/accounting
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/canonicalization
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/control
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/cui
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/debug
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/dhcp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/eap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/filter
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/operator-name
including files in directory /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/
main {
 security {
        user = "radiusd"
        group = "radiusd"
        allow_core_dumps = no
 }
        name = "radiusd"
        prefix = "/usr"
        localstatedir = "/var"
        logdir = "/var/log/radius"
        run_dir = "/var/run/radiusd"
}
main {
        name = "radiusd"
        prefix = "/usr"
        localstatedir = "/var"
        sbindir = "/usr/sbin"
        logdir = "/var/log/radius"
        run_dir = "/var/run/radiusd"
        libdir = "/usr/lib64/freeradius"
        radacctdir = "/var/log/radius/radacct"
        hostname_lookups = no
        max_request_time = 30
        cleanup_delay = 5
        max_requests = 16384
        pidfile = "/var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid"
        checkrad = "/usr/sbin/checkrad"
        debug_level = 0
        proxy_requests = yes
 log {
        stripped_names = no
        auth = no
        auth_badpass = no
        auth_goodpass = no
        colourise = yes
        msg_denied = "You are already logged in - access denied"
 }
 resources {
 }
 security {
        max_attributes = 200
        reject_delay = 1.000000
        status_server = yes
 }
}
radiusd: #### Loading Realms and Home Servers ####
 proxy server {
        retry_delay = 5
        retry_count = 3
        default_fallback = no
        dead_time = 120
        wake_all_if_all_dead = no
 }
 home_server localhost {
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        port = 1812
        type = "auth"
        secret = <<< secret >>>
        response_window = 20.000000
        response_timeouts = 1
        max_outstanding = 65536
        zombie_period = 40
        status_check = "status-server"
        ping_interval = 30
        check_interval = 30
        check_timeout = 4
        num_answers_to_alive = 3
        revive_interval = 120
  limit {
        max_connections = 16
        max_requests = 0
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 0
  }
  coa {
        irt = 2
        mrt = 16
        mrc = 5
        mrd = 30
  }
 }
 home_server_pool my_auth_failover {
        type = fail-over
        home_server = localhost
 }
 realm example.com {
        auth_pool = my_auth_failover
 }
 realm LOCAL {
 }
radiusd: #### Loading Clients ####
 client localhost {
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        require_message_authenticator = no
        secret = <<< secret >>>
        nas_type = "other"
        proto = "*"
  limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
 client localhost_ipv6 {
        ipv6addr = ::1
        require_message_authenticator = no
        secret = <<< secret >>>
  limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
Debugger not attached
radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####
 modules {
  # Loaded module rlm_always
  # Loading module "reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always reject {
        rcode = "reject"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "fail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always fail {
        rcode = "fail"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "ok" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always ok {
        rcode = "ok"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "handled" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always handled {
        rcode = "handled"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "invalid" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always invalid {
        rcode = "invalid"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "userlock" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always userlock {
        rcode = "userlock"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "notfound" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always notfound {
        rcode = "notfound"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "noop" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always noop {
        rcode = "noop"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "updated" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always updated {
        rcode = "updated"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_attr_filter
  # Loading module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.post-proxy {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy"
        key = "%{Realm}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.pre-proxy {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy"
        key = "%{Realm}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_reject {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject"
        key = "%{User-Name}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_challenge {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge"
        key = "%{User-Name}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.accounting_response {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response"
        key = "%{User-Name}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_cache
  # Loading module "cache_eap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cache_eap
  cache cache_eap {
        driver = "rlm_cache_rbtree"
        key = "%{%{control:State}:-%{%{reply:State}:-%{State}}}"
        ttl = 15
        max_entries = 0
        epoch = 0
        add_stats = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_chap
  # Loading module "chap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/chap
  # Loaded module rlm_date
  # Loading module "date" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/date
  date {
        format = "%b %e %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_detail
  # Loading module "detail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
  detail {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "auth_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail auth_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "reply_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail reply_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/reply-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail pre_proxy_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/pre-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail post_proxy_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/post-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_dhcp
  # Loading module "dhcp" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dhcp
  # Loaded module rlm_digest
  # Loading module "digest" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/digest
  # Loaded module rlm_dynamic_clients
  # Loading module "dynamic_clients" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dynamic_clients
  # Loaded module rlm_exec
  # Loading module "echo" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/echo
  exec echo {
        wait = yes
        program = "/bin/echo %{User-Name}"
        input_pairs = "request"
        output_pairs = "reply"
        shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loading module "exec" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/exec
  exec {
        wait = no
        input_pairs = "request"
        shell_escape = yes
        timeout = 10
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_expiration
  # Loading module "expiration" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Loaded module rlm_expr
  # Loading module "expr" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expr
  expr {
        safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /äéöüàâæçèéêëîïôœùûüaÿÄÉÖÜßÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸ"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_files
  # Loading module "files" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
  files {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize"
        acctusersfile = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/accounting"
        preproxy_usersfile = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/pre-proxy"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_linelog
  # Loading module "linelog" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/linelog"
        escape_filenames = no
        syslog_severity = "info"
        permissions = 384
        format = "This is a log message for %{User-Name}"
        reference = "messages.%{%{reply:Packet-Type}:-default}"
  }
  # Loading module "log_accounting" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog log_accounting {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/linelog-accounting"
        escape_filenames = no
        syslog_severity = "info"
        permissions = 384
        format = ""
        reference = "Accounting-Request.%{%{Acct-Status-Type}:-unknown}"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_logintime
  # Loading module "logintime" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/logintime
  logintime {
        minimum_timeout = 60
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_mschap
  # Loading module "mschap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/mschap
  mschap {
        use_mppe = yes
        require_encryption = no
        require_strong = no
        with_ntdomain_hack = yes
   passchange {
   }
        allow_retry = yes
        winbind_retry_with_normalised_username = no
  }
  # Loading module "ntlm_auth" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
  exec ntlm_auth {
        wait = yes
        program = "/path/to/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=MYDOMAIN --username=%{mschap:User-Name} --password=%{User-Password}"
        shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_pap
  # Loading module "pap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
  pap {
        normalise = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_passwd
  # Loading module "etc_passwd" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/passwd
  passwd etc_passwd {
        filename = "/etc/passwd"
        format = "*User-Name:Crypt-Password:"
        delimiter = ":"
        ignore_nislike = no
        ignore_empty = yes
        allow_multiple_keys = no
        hash_size = 100
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_preprocess
  # Loading module "preprocess" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/preprocess
  preprocess {
        huntgroups = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups"
        hints = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/hints"
        with_ascend_hack = no
        ascend_channels_per_line = 23
        with_ntdomain_hack = no
        with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no
        with_cisco_vsa_hack = no
        with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_radutmp
  # Loading module "radutmp" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/radutmp
  radutmp {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radutmp"
        username = "%{User-Name}"
        case_sensitive = yes
        check_with_nas = yes
        permissions = 384
        caller_id = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_realm
  # Loading module "IPASS" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm IPASS {
        format = "prefix"
        delimiter = "/"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "suffix" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm suffix {
        format = "suffix"
        delimiter = "@"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "realmpercent" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm realmpercent {
        format = "suffix"
        delimiter = "%"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "ntdomain" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm ntdomain {
        format = "prefix"
        delimiter = "\\"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_replicate
  # Loading module "replicate" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/replicate
  # Loaded module rlm_soh
  # Loading module "soh" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/soh
  soh {
        dhcp = yes
  }
  # Loading module "sradutmp" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sradutmp
  radutmp sradutmp {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/sradutmp"
        username = "%{User-Name}"
        case_sensitive = yes
        check_with_nas = yes
        permissions = 420
        caller_id = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_unix
  # Loading module "unix" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unix
  unix {
        radwtmp = "/var/log/radius/radwtmp"
  }
Creating attribute Unix-Group
  # Loaded module rlm_unpack
  # Loading module "unpack" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unpack
  # Loaded module rlm_utf8
  # Loading module "utf8" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/utf8
  # Loaded module rlm_perl
  # Loading module "perl" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/perl
  perl {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/perl/radius_linotp.pm"
        func_authorize = "authorize"
        func_authenticate = "authenticate"
        func_post_auth = "post_auth"
        func_accounting = "accounting"
        func_preacct = "preacct"
        func_checksimul = "checksimul"
        func_detach = "detach"
        func_xlat = "xlat"
        func_pre_proxy = "pre_proxy"
        func_post_proxy = "post_proxy"
        func_recv_coa = "recv_coa"
        func_send_coa = "send_coa"
  }
  instantiate {
  }
  # Instantiating module "reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "fail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "ok" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "handled" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "invalid" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "userlock" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "notfound" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "noop" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "updated" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject
[/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject]:11 Check item "FreeRADIUS-Response-Delay"    found in filter list for realm "DEFAULT". 
[/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject]:11 Check item "FreeRADIUS-Response-Delay-USec"       found in filter list for realm "DEFAULT". 
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response
  # Instantiating module "cache_eap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cache_eap
rlm_cache (cache_eap): Driver rlm_cache_rbtree (module rlm_cache_rbtree) loaded and linked
  # Instantiating module "detail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
  # Instantiating module "auth_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
rlm_detail (auth_log): 'User-Password' suppressed, will not appear in detail output
  # Instantiating module "reply_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "expiration" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Instantiating module "files" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[46]: Parse error (check) for entry DEFAULT: Unknown or invalid value "perl" for attribute Auth-Type
Failed reading /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

From this I can see the perl module being loaded but it seems something is not happy about the Auth-Type.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming, and is probably better suited for the [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I posted it here because I saw other questions regarding FreeRADIUS here. Any way I can simply move it to Unix SE?

Comment: Actually @stevieb FreeRADIUS implements its own interpreted policy language, and so it is, in a broad sense, related to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be an initialisation ordering issue.  When you use attribute references like `&Auth-Type` in the policy language (within any of the virtual server sections like `authorize { ... }`, `authenticate { ... }` etc... There's a multi-pass resolution process that occurs.  So even though the auth sections haven't been parsed at the point where you're setting values for `Auth-Type` is still works fine.

For the users file, which is an older legacy format from <= v2, there's no multi-pass processing. I can't remember in v3 without digging into the code which is initialised first, virtual servers or modules.  But if it's modules, then your problem is almost certainly, that the attribute resolution in the `files` module is being done before the `Auth-Type` sections are being processed, and the complete set of Auth-Type values has been built.

The simple fix for this, is to manually provide an enumeration value for `Auth-Type` in the custom dictionary file.

Try adding the following to `/etc/raddb/dictionary` or `/etc/freeradius/dictionary` on Debian based systems.

That should allow the files module to get the correct enumeration value for `Auth-Type` before any of the virtual servers are parsed.

```
VALUE   Auth-Type       perl        100
```