# FreeRADIUS Python Module “Unknown or invalid value ”Python“ for attribute Auth-Type”

Tags: python, python-2.7, freeradius

I am attempting to setup a FreeRadius Server (3.0.21) with Python Module. I just keep getting the error below when I try starting radiusd(radiusd -X):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[1]: Parse error (check) for entry DEFAULT: Unknown or invalid value "Python" for attribute Auth-Type
    Failed reading /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
    /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

Also I noticed the following which I am not sure is related

```
  # Instantiating module "python" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/python
Python version: 2.7.16 (default, Apr 17 2020, 18:29:03)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc-
*** instantiate ***
None
```

As per documentation, I have completed the following:

-added "DEFAULT Auth-type := python" as the first and only uncommented line in /etc/raddb/users

-added the module location to /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/python

-added the Auth-Type declarations in the site file (/etc/raddb/sites-available/default) see below.

Here are the contents of the relevant files with comments removed (these things are 99% comments)
**/etc/raddb/users**

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := python
```

**/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/python**

```
module = example
        python_path = ${modconfdir}/${.:name}

   mod_instantiate = ${.module}
#########Uncommented the following line #######
        func_instantiate = instantiate

        mod_detach = ${.module}
#       func_detach = detach
```

**/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default**

```
**authorize**
        #
        #  If you want to have a log of authentication requests,
        #  un-comment the following line.
#       auth_log

## Enable Python ##
        python     
#####
#
        #  The chap module will set 'Auth-Type := CHAP' if we are
        #  handling a CHAP request and Auth-Type has not already been set
        chap
```

authenticate
Auth-Type Pyton {
python
}

I also referred a similar question [freeRadius Perl Module Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106687/freeradius-perl-module-unknown-or-invalid-value-perl-for-attribute-auth-type) regarding Perl and tried enabling Perl which works fine for me but Python doesn't work following the same steps.

and finally the verbose startup log

```
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.21
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/share/freeradius/dictionary
including dictionary file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/share/freeradius/dictionary.dhcp
including dictionary file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/share/freeradius/dictionary.vqp
including dictionary file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/dictionary
including configuration file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
including configuration file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/proxy.conf
including configuration file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/clients.conf

including files in directory /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/
including configuration file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
including configuration file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
main {
    name = "radiusd"
    prefix = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21"
    localstatedir = "/usr/local/var"
    sbindir = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/bin"
    logdir = "/usr/local/var/log/radius"
    run_dir = "/usr/local/var/run/radiusd"
    libdir = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/lib"
    radacctdir = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct"
    hostname_lookups = no
    max_request_time = 30
    cleanup_delay = 5
    max_requests = 16384
    pidfile = "/usr/local/var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid"
    checkrad = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/bin/checkrad"
    debug_level = 0
    proxy_requests = yes
 log {
    stripped_names = no
    auth = no
    auth_badpass = no
    auth_goodpass = no
    colourise = yes
    msg_denied = "You are already logged in - access denied"
 }
 resources {
 }
 security {
    max_attributes = 200
    reject_delay = 1.000000
    status_server = yes
    allow_vulnerable_openssl = "no"
 }
}
radiusd: #### Loading Realms and Home Servers ####
 proxy server {
    retry_delay = 5
    retry_count = 3
    default_fallback = no
    dead_time = 120
    wake_all_if_all_dead = no
 }
 home_server localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    port = 1812
    type = "auth"
    secret = <<< secret >>>
    response_window = 20.000000
    response_timeouts = 1
    max_outstanding = 65536
    zombie_period = 40
    status_check = "status-server"
    ping_interval = 30
    check_interval = 30
    check_timeout = 4
    num_answers_to_alive = 3
    revive_interval = 120
  limit {
    max_connections = 16
    max_requests = 0
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 0
  }
  coa {
    irt = 2
    mrt = 16
    mrc = 5
    mrd = 30
  }
 }
 home_server_pool my_auth_failover {
    type = fail-over
    home_server = localhost
 }
 realm example.com {
    auth_pool = my_auth_failover
 }
 realm LOCAL {
 }
radiusd: #### Loading Clients ####
 client localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    require_message_authenticator = no
    secret = <<< secret >>>
    nas_type = "other"
    proto = "*"
  limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
 client localhost_ipv6 {
    ipv6addr = ::1
    require_message_authenticator = no
    secret = <<< secret >>
 }
Found debugger attached

radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####
 modules {
  # Loaded module rlm_detail
  # Loading module "auth_log" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail auth_log {
    filename = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "reply_log"
  detail reply_log {
    filename = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/reply-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  detail pre_proxy_log {
    filename = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/pre-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "post_proxy_log"
    filename = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/post-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }

  # Loading module "eap"
  eap {
    default_eap_type = "md5"
    timer_expire = 60
    ignore_unknown_eap_types = no
    cisco_accounting_username_bug = no
    max_sessions = 16384
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_exec
  # Loading module "echo" 
  exec echo {
    wait = yes
    program = "/bin/echo %{User-Name}"
    input_pairs = "request"
    output_pairs = "reply"
    shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_python
  # Loading module "python" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/python
  python {
    mod_instantiate = "example"
    func_instantiate = "instantiate"
    mod_authorize = "example"
    func_authorize = "authorize"
    mod_authenticate = "example"
    mod_preacct = "example"
    mod_accounting = "example"
    mod_checksimul = "example"
    mod_pre_proxy = "example"
    mod_post_proxy = "example"
    mod_post_auth = "example"
    mod_recv_coa = "example"
    mod_send_coa = "example"
    mod_detach = "example"
    python_path = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/python"
    cext_compat = yes
    pass_all_vps = no
    pass_all_vps_dict = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_utf8
  # Loading module "utf8" 
  # Loaded module rlm_ldap
  # Loading module "ldap" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap
  ldap {
    server = "localhost"
    port = 389
    identity = "cn=Directory Manager"
    password = <<< secret >>>
   sasl {
   }
    user_dn = "LDAP-UserDn"
   user {
    scope = "sub"
    access_positive = yes
    sasl {
    }
   }
   
   client {
    filter = "(objectClass=radiusClient)"
    scope = "sub"
    base_dn = "ou=people,ou=identities"
   }
   profile {
   }
   options {
    ldap_debug = 40
    chase_referrals = yes
    rebind = yes
    net_timeout = 1
    res_timeout = 10
    srv_timelimit = 3
    idle = 60
    probes = 3
    interval = 3
   }
   tls {
    start_tls = no
   }
  }

  # Loading module "fail" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always fail {
    rcode = "fail"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "ok" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always ok {
    rcode = "ok"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "handled" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always handled {
    rcode = "handled"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }

  # Loading module "userlock" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always userlock {
    rcode = "userlock"
    simulcount = 0
    mpp = no
  }

  # Loaded module rlm_perl
  # Loading module "perl" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/perl
  perl {
    filename = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/perl/example.pl"
    func_authorize = "authorize"
    func_authenticate = "authenticate"
    func_post_auth = "post_auth"
    func_accounting = "accounting"
    func_preacct = "preacct"
    func_checksimul = "checksimul"
    func_detach = "detach"
    func_xlat = "xlat"
    func_pre_proxy = "pre_proxy"
    func_post_proxy = "post_proxy"
    func_recv_coa = "recv_coa"
    func_send_coa = "send_coa"
    perl_flags = "-T"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_digest
  # Loading module "digest" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/digest
  # Loaded module rlm_date
  # Loading module "date" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/date
  date {
    format = "%b %e %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
    utc = no
  }
  # Loading module "wispr2date" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/date
  date wispr2date {
    format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
    utc = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_preprocess
  # Loading module "preprocess" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/preprocess
  preprocess {
    huntgroups = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups"
    hints = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/hints"
    with_ascend_hack = no
    ascend_channels_per_line = 23
    with_ntdomain_hack = no
    with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no
    with_cisco_vsa_hack = no
    with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_pap
  # Loading module "pap" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
  pap {
    normalise = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_expr
  # Loading module "expr" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expr
  expr {
    safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /äéöüàâæçèéêëîïôœùûüaÿÄÉÖÜßÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸ"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_radutmp
  # Loading module "radutmp" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/radutmp
  radutmp {
    filename = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radutmp"
    username = "%{User-Name}"
    case_sensitive = yes
    check_with_nas = yes
    permissions = 384
    caller_id = yes
  }
  
  # Loaded module rlm_unix
  # Loading module "unix" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unix
  unix {
    radwtmp = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radwtmp"
  }
Creating attribute Unix-Group
  # Loading module "detail" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
  detail {
    filename = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d"
    header = "%t"
    permissions = 384
    locking = no
    escape_filenames = no
    log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_attr_filter

  attr_filter attr_filter.post-proxy {
    filename = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy"
    key = "%{Realm}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.pre-proxy {
    filename = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy"
    key = "%{Realm}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_reject {
    filename = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject"
    key = "%{User-Name}"
    relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_challenge {
    filename = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge"
    key = "%{User-Name}"
    relaxed = no
  }
 
 
  # Loading module "exec" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/exec
  exec {
    wait = no
    input_pairs = "request"
    shell_escape = yes
    timeout = 10
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_files
  # Loading module "files" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
  files {
    filename = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize"
    acctusersfile = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/accounting"
    preproxy_usersfile = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/pre-proxy"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_replicate
  # Loading module "replicate" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/replicate
  # Loaded module rlm_chap
  # Loading module "chap" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/chap
  # Loaded module rlm_unpack
  # Loading module "unpack" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unpack
  # Loaded module rlm_logintime
  # Loading module "logintime" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/logintime
  logintime {
    minimum_timeout = 60
  }
 
  # Loaded module rlm_mschap
  # Loading module "mschap" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/mschap
  mschap {
    use_mppe = yes
    require_encryption = no
    require_strong = no
    with_ntdomain_hack = yes
   passchange {
   }
    allow_retry = yes
    winbind_retry_with_normalised_username = no
    use_open_directory = yes
  }
 
  # Instantiating module "eap" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_md5
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_leap
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_gtc
   gtc {
    challenge = "Password: "
    auth_type = "PAP"
   }
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_tls
   tls {
    tls = "tls-common"
   }
   tls-config tls-common {
    verify_depth = 0
    ca_path = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/certs"
    pem_file_type = yes
    private_key_file = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/certs/server.pem"
    certificate_file = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/certs/server.pem"
    ca_file = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/certs/ca.pem"
    private_key_password = <<< secret >>>
    dh_file = "/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/certs/dh"
    fragment_size = 1024
    include_length = yes
    auto_chain = yes
    check_crl = no
    check_all_crl = no
    cipher_list = "DEFAULT"
    cipher_server_preference = no
    ecdh_curve = "prime256v1"
    disable_tlsv1 = yes
    disable_tlsv1_1 = yes
    tls_max_version = "1.2"
    tls_min_version = "1.2"
    cache {
        enable = no
        lifetime = 24
        max_entries = 255
    }
    verify {
        skip_if_ocsp_ok = no
    }
    ocsp {
        enable = no
        override_cert_url = yes
        url = "http://127.0.0.1/ocsp/"
        use_nonce = yes
        timeout = 0
        softfail = no
    }
   }
Please use tls_min_version and tls_max_version instead of disable_tlsv1
Please use tls_min_version and tls_max_version instead of disable_tlsv1_2
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_ttls
   ttls {
    tls = "tls-common"
    default_eap_type = "md5"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    include_length = yes
    require_client_cert = no
   }
tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_peap
   peap {
    tls = "tls-common"
    default_eap_type = "mschapv2"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    proxy_tunneled_request_as_eap = yes
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    soh = no
    require_client_cert = no
   }
tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_mschapv2
   mschapv2 {
    with_ntdomain_hack = no
    send_error = no
   }
  # Instantiating module "python" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/python
Python version: 2.7.16 (default, Apr 17 2020, 18:29:03)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc-
*** instantiate ***
None
  # Instantiating module "ldap" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap
rlm_ldap: libldap vendor: OpenLDAP, version: 20428
   accounting {
    reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}}"
   }
   post-auth {
    reference = "."
   }
rlm_ldap (ldap): Initialising connection pool
   pool {
    start = 5
    min = 3
    max = 32
    spare = 10
    uses = 0
    lifetime = 0
    cleanup_interval = 30
    idle_timeout = 60
    retry_delay = 30
    spread = no
   }
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (0), 1 of 32 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://localhost:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (1), 1 of 31 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://localhost:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (2), 1 of 30 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://localhost:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (3), 1 of 29 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://localhost:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (4), 1 of 28 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://localhost:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
  # Instantiating module "reject" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "fail" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "ok" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "handled" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "invalid" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "userlock" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "notfound" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "noop" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "updated" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "perl" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/perl
  # Instantiating module "preprocess" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/preprocess
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/hints
  # Instantiating module "pap" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
  # Instantiating module "linelog" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  # Instantiating module "log_accounting" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  # Instantiating module "detail" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response
  # Instantiating module "files" from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
reading pairlist file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[1]: Parse error (check) for entry DEFAULT: Unknown or invalid value "Python" for attribute Auth-Type
Failed reading /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems, I have found the answer by following the other post

Added the following to `/etc/raddb/dictionary`

```
VALUE   Auth-Type       python        100
```

I can see now that the module is being initialised. But somehow the authentication is failing which needs bit more investigation

**Test Command and output**

```
radtest bob hello localhost 1812 testing123
Sent Access-Request Id 28 from 0.0.0.0:51983 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
    User-Name = "bob"
    User-Password = "hello"
    NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.0.236
    NAS-Port = 1812
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "hello"
Received Access-Reject Id 28 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:51983 length 43
    Reply-Message = "Hello from rlm_python"
(0) -: Expected Access-Accept got Access-Reject
```

**Logs from raddb**

```
(0) Received Access-Request Id 28 from 127.0.0.1:51983 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
(0)   User-Name = "bob"
(0)   User-Password = "hello"
(0)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.0.236
(0)   NAS-Port = 1812
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0x7d14fda6b89582a0a18ac865fc967103
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)     policy filter_username {
(0)       if (&User-Name) {
(0)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(0)       if (&User-Name)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(0)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(0)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(0)     [preprocess] = ok
*** authorize ***
*** radlog call in authorize ***

(('User-Name', 'bob'), ('User-Password', 'hello'), ('NAS-IP-Address', '192.168.0.236'), ('NAS-Port', '1812'), ('Message-Authenticator', '0x7d14fda6b89582a0a18ac865fc967103'), ('Event-Timestamp', 'Jul 16 2020 09:14:33 BST'))

{}
authorize - 'reply:Reply-Message' = 'Hello from rlm_python'
authorize - 'config:Cleartext-Password' = 'hello'
(0)     [python] = ok
(0)     [chap] = noop
(0)     [mschap] = noop
(0)     [digest] = noop
(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "bob", looking up realm NULL
(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(0)     [suffix] = noop
(0) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(0)     [eap] = noop
(0) files: users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 1
(0)     [files] = ok
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing connection (0): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 74 seconds
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing connection (1): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 74 seconds
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing connection (2): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 74 seconds
rlm_ldap (ldap): You probably need to lower "min"
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing connection (3): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 74 seconds
rlm_ldap (ldap): You probably need to lower "min"
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing connection (4): Hit idle_timeout, was idle for 74 seconds
rlm_ldap (ldap): You probably need to lower "min"
rlm_ldap (ldap): 0 of 0 connections in use.  You  may need to increase "spare"
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (5), 1 of 32 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://localhost:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (5)
(0) ldap: EXPAND (uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})
(0) ldap:    --> (uid=bob)
(0) ldap: Performing search in "ou=people,ou=identities" with filter "(uid=bob)", scope "sub"
(0) ldap: Waiting for search result...
(0) ldap: Search returned no results
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (5)
Need 2 more connections to reach min connections (3)
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (6), 1 of 31 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://localhost:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
(0)     [ldap] = notfound
(0)     [expiration] = noop
(0)     [logintime] = noop
(0) pap: WARNING: Auth-Type already set.  Not setting to PAP
(0)     [pap] = noop
(0)   } # authorize = ok
(0) Found Auth-Type = python
(0) Auth-Type sub-section not found.  Ignoring.
(0) # Executing group from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0) Failed to authenticate the user
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(0) # Executing group from file /usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.21/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(0) attr_filter.access_reject: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(0) attr_filter.access_reject:    --> bob
(0) attr_filter.access_reject: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(0)     [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(0)     [eap] = noop
(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)       else {
(0)         [noop] = noop
(0)       } # else = noop
(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)   } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(0) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
Waking up in 0.2 seconds.
Waking up in 0.7 seconds.
(0) Sending delayed response
(0) Sent Access-Reject Id 28 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:51983 length 43
(0)   Reply-Message = "Hello from rlm_python"
Waking up in 3.9 seconds.
(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 28 with timestamp +74
Ready to process requests
```